# How can I SELECT a predefined set of values and their counts?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For the sake of setting up the problem, let's say I want to show total sales amounts for each of three people on my sales team. Bob and Alice have sales, but James is a new salesman and has no sales.

There's a table called `sales` with data like so:

| id | seller | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alice | $5 |
| 1 | Bob | $4 |
| 2 | Alice | $16 |
| 3 | Bob | $6 |

I can use SUM like:

```
SELECT seller, SUM(amount)
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller
```

...to produce a result set like:

| seller | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | $21 |
| Bob | $10 |

However, this does not include James who is new and has no sales. My desired result set is:

| seller | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | $21 |
| Bob | $10 |
| James | $0 |

**Q: How can I get this desired result set which includes James's (zero) sales?**

Note that the list of Salespeople is not stored in any other table; I expect I will need to hard code it into my query, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have a dedicated table of sellers which you want to appear in your report.  Sans this, we can use an inline union subquery containing all seller names.

```
SELECT t.seller, COALESCE(SUM(s.amount), 0) AS total_sales
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Alice' AS seller UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'James'
) t
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON s.seller = t.seller
GROUP BY
    t.seller;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION:

```
WITH people AS(
  SELECT 'alice' as person 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'bob'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'james'
)

SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN sales ON people.person = sales.seller
```

now you can use `people` as if it were a table. Grouping and summing the nulls produced by the left join will result in zeroes for james

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . if you need to hardcode the sales people, then perhaps you already know the new ones.  If that is the case, you can use `union all`:

```
select seller, sum(sales)
from sales
group by seller
union all
select 'James', 0;
```

If you don't want to list all sales people, but have a super list of the new ones, you can also use a `full join`:

```
select seller, coalesce(sum(s.sales), 0)
from sales s full join
     (select 'James' as seller union all
      select 'Bob' as seller
     ) news
     using (seller);
```

This can be convenient if you have a long list of `sellers` and don't want to list all of them.